# Prestashop csv import - multiple images on single product

Tags: csv, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am attempting to mass upload products via csv import and using images that are stored on the host server however(URL Links) once the products upload i will get multiple images for one product that are not associated to the product.

I am running Prestashop 1.6.1.3

While uploading I have set my language on my Window PC to use semicolon separators instead of the comma so that my csv files work with prestashop.

I have had no problem doing this in the past with comma separated csv files and changing the separator value to the comma as instructed by prestashop but that upload list did not contain commas in the product description. This new list i am having trouble with does contain commas in the product description hence why I changed to a semicolon separated file.

**What I learned after failed uploads:**
Quotation marks will cause the descriptions to not load properly - solution was to replace 5" and 6' to 5in and 6ft when describing measurements.

**Problem:**
Import works fine but only uploads a certain number of products I have about 250 and probably 15 upload. When viewing the product in the admin portal everything is looking good except when you look at the images uploaded. Multiple images that do not correspond to the product appear. Images are saved by their ID/SKU number and end in .jpg

**What I think is the problem:**
Some image names contain a "-" in them for example XR1234-S.jpg 
I believe that the dash "-" is causing the failure but cannot seem to resolve this even after removing the "-". Other possible problem could be since i change the separator value to semicolon the forward slash in the URL is not being recognized.